# Word VBA Script To find hyperlinked texts

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to find texts in a word documents which are linked?

For eg : Word "Introduction" has a hyperlink

I want to get the word Introduction.

Comment: What code do you have so far? And what will you do with the text when you find it?

Answer (score 1):

To find them all use this sub:

```
Sub qSolution()

    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    For Each HL In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        Debug.Print HL.Range.Text
    Next
End Sub
```

To find any single one which number you know (first in below example) use this code:

```
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Text
```

In both situations you get text in immediate window in IDE.